# Change the number formatting in Plotly funnel (R)

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have a funnel plot below:

```
val = as.list(df[,2])
txt = as.list(df[,1])

library(plotly)


fig <- plot_ly()

fig <- fig  %>%  
  add_trace(
    type = "funnel",
    textinfo = "value+percent initial",
    opacity = 0.65,
    x = val,
    y = txt,
    connector = list(line = list(color = "royalblue", dash = "dot", width = 3)), 
    colorbar = list(exponentformat = 'none')
  )

fig <- fig %>% 
  layout(
    hovermode = "closest"
  )

fig
```

I want to change the formatting below to another option. Preferably a full int.

[image]

Instead of the 11k, I want the entire number. Thanks!

Comment: I believe you answer is in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72087095/is-there-any-way-to-format-the-digits-in-the-funnel-chart-for-plotly-for-python

Answer (score 0):

May use hoverformat parameter in xaxis or yaxis

```
plot_ly(data=dt_toPlot,type="funnel",
               x=~n,y=~status,opacity=0.7,
               hoverinfo="name+x+y+percent initial+percent previous")%>%
          layout(yaxis = list(title="",categoryarray = ~status),
                 xaxis = list(hoverformat = '.0f'))%>%
            config(displayModeBar = FALSE),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same doubt and it was hard to find an answer to this problem in R. But, I look after the same problem in Python and then I found a solution to that.

```
fig <- fig  %>%  
  add_trace(
    type = "funnel",
    textinfo = "value+percent initial",
    opacity = 0.65,
    x = val,
    y = txt,
    connector = list(line = list(color = "royalblue", dash = "dot", width = 3)), 
    colorbar = list(exponentformat = 'none'),
    textinfo: "x",
    texttemplate = '%{value:,.3~s}'
  )

fig <- fig %>% 
  layout(
    hovermode = "closest"
  )

fig
```

I just add two lines on the code, one to refer what to display and other to show the format that I want.

It's important to mention that this format (%{value:,.3~s}) behavior is like that:

> Example: 20200 -> 20.2k

On the question, you said that you want an integer number, so it needs to change the format type, that is based on d3-format's syntax.
You can check on: https://github.com/d3/d3-format

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that I like for the sheer flexibility is to add columns to my data with the text I'd like to appear both on the graphic and on hover.  After adding the columns, you can use the `text=` argument to specify the column that contains the text you'd like to appear on hover, and the `texttemplate=` argument to specify the column that contains the text you'd like to appear on the graphic.

Take this data for example:

```
fundat<-data.frame(Stage=c("1. Beginning","2. Act 2","3. Act 3","4. Act 4","5. End"),Amount=c(948000,872000,414000,297000,119000))
```

Say we'd like:

- Numbers do not give you the 11.995K treatment.
- Specific additional metrics to appear in the text on some of the funnel stages (or all, the world is your oyster).
- Hover text to contain whatever arbitrary information we want.

Here's a bit of code adding example text columns:

```
fundat2<-fundat%>%
 mutate(StandardTxt=ifelse(Stage %in% c("1. Beginning"),Amount,
         ifelse(Stage %in% c("2. Act 2"),
         paste0(Amount,"<br> (",round((Amount[Stage %in% c("2. Act 2")]/Amount[Stage %in% 
c("1. Beginning")])*100,1),"% of Beginnings)"),
          ifelse(Stage %in% c("3. Act 3"),
          paste0(Amount,"<br> (",round((Amount[Stage %in% c("3. Act 3")]/Amount[Stage %in% c("2. Act 2")])*100,1),"% of Act 2 & <br>",round((Amount[Stage %in% c("3. Act 
3")]/Amount[Stage %in% c("4. Act 4")])*100,1), " of Act 4)"),Amount))))%>%
mutate(HoverTxt=paste0("The first digit of the amount is 
",paste0(substr(Amount,1,1))))
```

This gives us a dataframe looking like this:
[image]

We've now made a column called StandardTxt with the text we'd like to appear on the graphic, and a column called HoverTxt with the text we'd like to appear on hover. Note that `<br>` is an html line break, and when rendering the plot the break will appear in your text.

To use the text in the plot:

```
plot_ly(fundat2,type='funnel',x=~Amount,y=~Stage,text=~HoverTxt,hoverinfo="text",texttemplate=~StandardTxt)
```

Our resulting plot with the cursor over the "Act 2" funnel stages displays like:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Note:  Make sure your numbers aren't getting the scientific notation treatment ahead of your plotting!

**When R is already putting your numbers into scientific notation**

Consider

```
fundat<-data.frame(Stage=c("1. Beginning","2. Act 2","3. Act 3","4. Act 4","5. End"),Amount=c(948000000,872000000,414000000,297000000,119000000))
```

We're dealing with much larger numbers than the above example.  When I look at fundat, I see:

[image]

This scientific notation will carry on down through our example all the way to our plot!  To remedy this, you can use `format()` to remove the scientific notation.

```
fundat2<-fundat%>%
mutate(Amount=format(Amount,scientific=FALSE))
```

In my experience, this breaks the code I'd used for the text strings, so I had to wrap the references to "Amount" in my percentage calculations with `as.numeric()` like so:

```
fundat2<-fundat%>%
  mutate(Amount=format(Amount,scientific=FALSE))%>%
  mutate(StandardTxt=ifelse(Stage %in% c("1. Beginning"),Amount,
         ifelse(Stage %in% c("2. Act 2"),paste0(Amount,"<br>(",round((as.numeric(Amount[Stage %in% c("2. Act 2")])/as.numeric(Amount[Stage 
%in% c("1. Beginning")]))*100,1),"% of Beginnings)"),
             ifelse(Stage %in% c("3. Act 3"),paste0(Amount,"<br> (",round((as.numeric(Amount[Stage %in% c("3. Act 3")])/as.numeric(Amount[Stage 
%in% c("2. Act 2")]))*100,1),"% of Act 2 & <br>",round((as.numeric(Amount[Stage 
%in% c("3. Act 3")])/as.numeric(Amount[Stage %in% c("4. Act 4")]))*100,1), " of 
Act 4)"),Amount))))%>%
  mutate(HoverTxt=paste0("The first digit of the amount is 
",paste0(substr(Amount,1,1))))
```

This allows that same `plotly` code above to yield a plot like this:

[image]