# Is there any way to format the digits in the Funnel chart for Plotly for Python?

Tags: python, plotly-python

I have a funnel graph in which some of the values are greater than 9000, which are shown with the dot notation with a K (indicating thousands at the end).

I've spent 20 minutes looking on Google and in the Plotly documentation, and I haven't been able to find a clear response on how to format the digits.

This is the input data

This is the code I'm using

```
fig = px.funnel(userChurnByEventCategory, x='users', y='event_category', 
    title="User churn", labels={'event_category': 'Event categories'})

fig.show()
```

This is the graph. You can see that the top values have the letter K.

How do I format all numbers to just have a dot (or a comma) to separate thousands, and remove that confusing K letter? I've been asked to do so.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update the text format using the update_traces command and the texttemplate attribute:

```
fig = px.funnel(userChurnByEventCategory, x='users', y='event_category', 
    title="User churn", labels={'event_category': 'Event categories'})

fig.update_traces(texttemplate="%{value:,d}")

fig.show()
```

The ",d" part is where you actually define the format using d3-format's syntax

To use the "." instead of the "," as a thousand separator (and in  consequence use "," as decimal separator) add this line of code before the fig.show():

```
# change the thousand separator to . and the decimal seperator to ,
fig.update_layout(separators = ',.')
```

Comment: Thank you! This almost solves my issue. The only problem is that this shows the numbers with a comma as thousand-separator symbol. I need a dot. I've tried writing value: .d, but it doesn't show any separator

Comment: I now added an instruction on how to achieve that